# ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection Fails with Name Error: uninitialized constant Arel::Visitors::MySQL

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I was using ActiveRecod with my sinatra app and mysql db which was working fine till yesterday. Today i am having strange errors with it. On using mysql2 as adapter the following error is encountered.

```
irb(main):008:0> ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter=>"mysql2",:host=>"localhost",:username=>"tushar",:password=>"samael321",:database=>"Chat_test")
NameError: uninitialized constant Arel::Visitors::MySQL
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:466:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:462:in `load_missing_constant'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing_with_dependencies'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:128:in `<class:AbstractMysqlAdapter>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:6:in `<module:ConnectionAdapters>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:5:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:69:in `establish_connection'
from (irb):8
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I am unable to figure out any thing about the issue on net.

My ruby version is as below:

```
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
```

My gem version is as below

```
1.8.11
```

**SOLVED**

Suddenly i have stopped to encounter any error for the same. I have removed the ruby 1.8 that was earlier present, after which i am not facing an error. Still any explanation to this is required as i dont know what solved the problem.

Comment: Did you just switch the existing project to mysql2? If not, what did you do between when it last worked and now?

Comment: Well i was using Mysql2::Client.new earlier, then i switched to Active_record which was working fine. Then I installed rails. after that it is not working. Mysql2 is working fine though.